# How I can match two pattern in text file

Tags: python, regex, text

How I can match two pattern (select both line that are contain "205" and "212") in text file as below and get them.
Now my code is get the result only one pattern. Thank you for all.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^\S+ \S+ \S+ ([205][212])\d+.*$")
```

##### My text file

```
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.143.209 205316002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205316004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205316004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.165 205315402 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315404 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315404 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.18.113 212359002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205359004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205359004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.161 212315002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.168 205315702 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315704 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315704 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```py
^\S+ \S+ \S+ (?:205|212)\d.*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MTuAa3/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+ \S+ \S+` - three one space separated words
- `(?:205|212)` - either `205` or `212`
- `\d` - digit
- `.*$` the rest of the line, end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `(?=(^.*205))(?=(.*212.*$))|(?=(^.*212))(?=(.*205.*$))`

Code:

```
import re

text = """
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.143.209 205316002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205316004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205316004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.165 205315402 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315404 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315404 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.18.113 212359002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205359004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205359004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.161 212315002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.168 205315702 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315704 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315704 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
"""
pattern = "(?=(^.*205))(?=(.*212.*$))|(?=(^.*212))(?=(.*205.*$))"

print(re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Output:

```
[('mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.18.113 212359002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205359004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205', 'mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.18.113 212359002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205359004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205359004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan'), ('mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.161 212315002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205', 'mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.17.161 212315002 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205315004 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205315004 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan')]
```